# php unicode text not showing after insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I want to insert unicode text into my mysql database. when i put "আবুল কাশেম"(Bengali language) in input field to insert. it's inserted properly but it's not showing "আবুল কাশেম" it shows "à¦†à¦¬à§à¦² à¦•à¦¾à¦¶à§‡à¦®" this.how can i solve it.

**data type: VARCHAR** and **Collation: utf8_unicode_ci**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title><title>
</head>
<body>
 <label for="date">আপনার পূর্ণ নাম</label>
 <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="আপনার পূর্ণ নাম">
 <button type="submit" name="register" >রেজিস্ট্রেশন</button>

</body>
</html>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fullname']);

 $insert = "insert into users (name) values ('$name')";
        $run_insert = mysqli_query($con,$insert);
            if($run_insert){
            echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";
            }

        }

 ?>
```

Comment: Post your HTML markup.

Comment: Mojibake.  For PHP, you need `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` to declare that your text is in utf8.